# Как отформатировать дату и время?

Tags: android, kotlin, дата

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как на языке kotlin привести строку "2022-07-13T07:58:57.835201Z" к формату 13.07.2022 07:58? Можно ли это сделать с помощью класса SimpleDateFormat или с помощью методов класса String?

Comment: Как-то так `String pattern = "MM-dd-yyyy";
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
String date = simpleDateFormat.format(new Date());
System.out.println(date);`

Comment: @DanilApsadikov Насколько я понял, так можно преобразовать только сегодняшнюю дату...А как преобразовать именно строку "2022-07-13T07:58:57.835201Z", пришедшую с сервера именно в таком формате?

Comment: Любую дату можно

Comment: @DanilApsadikov 
При попытке так сделать:

val pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy"
val simpleDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat(pattern)
val newDate = simpleDateFormat.format("2022-07-13T07:58:57.835201Z")

получаю java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это java, но можно переписать на kotlin

```
String dateString = "2022-07-13T07:58:57.835201Z";
SimpleDateFormat currentFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS'Z'");
Date date = currentFormat.parse(dateString);
SimpleDateFormat targetFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
String formattedDate = targetFormat.format(date);
System.out.println(formattedDate); //2022-07-13 08:12
```

Comment: Спасибо! Уже переписал и разобрался, всё работает как надо)